# Neo4J variable-length pattern

Tags: neo4j, path, variable-length

Is it possible to write a Cypher query with a variable-length patter, that specifies that nodes between the start and end node can only be nodes with a certain property?

I think that a query like the following would match all of the below patterns:

`MATCH p=(n:Node {foo:"True"})<-[:REL*0..2]-(:Node)<-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})`

```
(n:Node {foo:"True"})                                        <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
(n:Node {foo:"True"})                    <-[:REL]-(:Node)    <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
(n:Node {foo:"True"})  <-[:REL]-(:Node)  <-[:REL]-(:Node)    <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
```

I imagine it "copying" the `<-[:REL]-(:Node)` part of the query 0 to 2 times in between the `(n:Node {foo:"True"})` and  `<-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})` query parts and constructing some kind of UNION of the matches.

Is this the right way to think about it? And how would i make the variable-lenght query match only paths where the middle nodes have the property `{bar:"True"}` in the middle nodes like so:

```
(n:Node {foo:"True"})                                                    <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
(n:Node {foo:"True"})                          <-[:REL]-({bar:"True})    <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
(n:Node {foo:"True"})  <-[:REL]-({bar:"True})  <-[:REL]-({bar:"True})    <-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})
```

Would the query below be the right approach?

`MATCH p=(n:Node {foo:"True"})<-[:REL*0..2]-(:Node {bar:"True"})<-[:REL]-(:Node {bar:"True"})`

It appears to me that this is not the case. Can somebody clearify on where I am going wrong in my thinking process?

Comment: You can use APOC with nodes filter: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/graph-querying/

Comment: It'd be easy if "bar" was a label or property of the relationship - if that's compatible with your data model.

Comment: @DavidPond unfortunately it is only a node property - like in my example given, but please feel free to provide a solution if the property were of the relationship (although for my case it is not usable)

Comment: @nimrodserok My question still remains...How can I think about the variable-length pattern. And is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be easy if foo were a relationship property, instead of a node property.

Create a simple example:

```
MERGE (a:Node {name:"a", foo:True})
MERGE (b:Node {name:"b", bar:True})
MERGE (c:Node {name:"c", bar:True})
MERGE (d:Node {name:"d", bar:False})
MERGE (e:Node {name:"e", bar:True})
MERGE (a)<-[:REL]-(b)
MERGE (b)<-[:REL]-(c)
MERGE (a)<-[:REL]-(d)
MERGE (d)<-[:REL]-(e)
```

I think you want to match nodes b and c, but not e because we'd have to traverse d which has foo:False.

Make bar a property on the relationships:

```
MATCH ()<-[r:REL]-(n:Node)
SET r.bar = n.bar
```

Now you can write:

```
MATCH (:Node {foo:True})<-[:REL*0..2 {bar:True}]-(n:Node)
RETURN n.name
```

Which returns b and c as required.

Comment: Looks easy and definitely works! BUT my dataset is about 150 million nodes and I dont want to change the relationships this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH path=(:Node {foo:True})-[:REL*0..2]-(n:Node {bar:True})
WHERE all(x in nodes(path) WHERE x.bar=True OR x.foo=True)
RETURN n.name
```